# How to put multiple settings in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

My dict is below

`stopwords.txt` have all the stopwords

and `synonym.txt` have football,soccer

```
abc = [
{'id':1, 'name': 'christiano ronaldo', 'description': 'football@fifa.com', 'type': 'football'},
{'id':2, 'name': 'lionel messi', 'description': 'soccer@fifa.com','type': 'soccer'},
{'id':3, 'name': 'sachin', 'description': 'was', 'type': 'cricket'}
]
```

- I have two txt files `stopwords.txt` and `synonym.txt`
- If I am searching stopwords then those document should not return
- I need to apply settings on `name` and `description`

```
resp = es.search(index="players",body={
"query": {
"query_string": {
"fields": ["name^2","description^2"],
"query": "was football*"
}
}})
```

My out

```
{'took': 17,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 2.345461,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'players',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '3',
    '_score': 2.345461,
    '_source': {'id': 3,
     'name': 'sachin',
     'description': 'was',
     'type': 'cricket'}},
   {'_index': 'players',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '1',
    '_score': 2.0,
    '_source': {'id': 1,
     'name': 'christiano ronaldo',
     'description': 'football@fifa.com',
     'type': 'football'}}]}}
```

Expected out is below

```
{'took': 2,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 2.0,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'players',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '1',
    '_score': 2.0,
    '_source': {'id': 1,
     'name': 'christiano ronaldo',
     'description': 'football@fifa.com',
     'type': 'football'}},
   {'_index': 'players',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '2',
    '_score': 2.0,
    '_source': {'id': 2,
     'name': 'lionel messi',
     'description': 'soccer@fifa.com',
     'type': 'soccer'}}]}}
```

Comment: how do you get the document with id = 2, for your search query term = `was football`

Comment: because in synonymn football= soccer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to define both synonym and stop words, instead of defining it in a file, you can also pass the synonym in the settings itself that way changing it will be much easy, you just need to close the index, update the synonym list and again open the index.

Also, if you are using `english` content, Elasticsearch also have a default stop worlds list, which has `was` already, you can take a look at all the default stop words [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.java#L48)

Now use below setting and mapping to create your index

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "synonym_en": {
                        "type": "synonym_graph",
                        "synonyms": [
                            "football, soccer"
                        ]
                    },
                    "english_stop": {
                        "type": "stop",
                        "stopwords": "_english_"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "english_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "english_stop",
                            "synonym_en"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "english_analyzer"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "english_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And after that use same query, now you should be able to get your expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below index mapping, to include multiple files in `stopwords_path`, and then use the custom analyzer on both `name` and `description` fields.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "stop-analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "stop_words_1",
                        "stop_words_2"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "stop_words_1": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords_path": "stopwords.txt"
                },
                "stop_words_2": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords_path": "synonym.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "stop-analyzer"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "stop-analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in synonymn football, soccer